# Video App records surveillance video to local Parent folder (PF). In PF, subfolder created/named by date. How to delete SF after X days

Tags: windows, automation

I use a video surveillance program that records surveillance video to local Parent folder (Reolink). Every day the program creates a subfolder in the Reolink folder with date of creation. Example today's date is August 18, 2023 - the subfolder will be created and named 08182023. Inside of 08182023, every 5 minutes a video file is created and as an example is named Backyard Duo 2 000000-000500.mp4 (this would be midnight to 12:05am file).The subfolder can contain as many as 375+ files. Each subfolder is approximately 200GB. After X days I want to delete the subfolder based on its creation date (in this example 08182023 folder was created on August 18, 2023). I want to delete the subfolder contents as well. So how to automatically delete the subfolder and contents after X days. I do not want to delete the main Reolink folder. Thanks for any help. I'm a total noob - I looked powershell commands and I tried to use this in a command line as a test but it errored. "Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\Users\mhg\Dropbox\Reolink' -File -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-9))}| Remove-Item -Force"